# Separate sub string into another file based on criteria - VBA

Tags: excel, substring, vba

I have a list of records that I would like to separate into a different file based
 on a criterion, which is 'if any of the records contain a **5***, then append into a file as a list (.csv if possible)
the result 'only' (e.g. *502* and *514*).  It is assumed the file has already been created for this purpose.

I am using VBA Excel.

Here is an example of some records:

```
Description: French Examination no: ****
Exam Result: 487

Description: French examination no: ****
Exam Result: 377

Description: French examination no: ****
Exam Result: 502

Description: French examination no: ****
Exam Result: 514
```

I know that the use of the **split** function would be used but I am unfamiliar with it.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use the following code snippet:

```
astrRec = split( strRecord )
for each varItem in astrRec 
   if varItem like "5*" then
      'append to first file
   endif
next
```